# cant get request body sent from retrofit in php

Tags: php, android, retrofit

I'm trying to send multiple image to server using retrofit 
what i'am doing is to send a map of RequestBody and this is my code

```
  @Multipart
@POST("imageuload")
Call<ResponseBody> postImage(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> files );
```

and in my activity

```
   Map<String, RequestBody> filestosend = new HashMap<>();
                for (int pos = 0; pos < files.size(); pos++) {
                    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), files.get(pos));
                    filestosend.put("photo_" + String.valueOf(pos + 1), requestBody);
                }




                Call<ResponseBody> call = apiSerice.postImage(filestosend);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            try {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),response.body().string(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }else {
                            try {
                                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                                alert.setMessage(response.errorBody().string());
                                alert.show();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();


                    }
                });
```

and when i want to test for what i'am getting it return an empty respons from server and i get nothing in my response ..

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

i even tested with a single request body

```
  RequestBody test = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "test");

                Call<ResponseBody> call = apiSerice.postImage(test);
```

but i am still getting an empty response in my on response 
i will appreciate any help or comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multipart uploads can be accessed in PHP through [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php). The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) has the following to say regarding `php://input`:

> php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

A full working example (minus correct endpoint URL, hard coded byte arrays):

```
public class Sample {

    interface SampleService {
        @Multipart
        @POST("/test.php")
        Call<ResponseBody> postImage(@Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://...").build();
        SampleService service = retrofit.create(SampleService.class);

        RequestBody file1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), new byte[]{0x00});
        MultipartBody.Part part1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("A kitten", "Kitten.jpg", file1);

        RequestBody file2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), new byte[]{0x00});
        MultipartBody.Part part2 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("Another kitten", "Kitten2.jpg", file2);

        System.out.println(service.postImage(Arrays.asList(part1, part2)).execute().body().string());
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
<?php var_dump($_FILES); ?>
```

Output from client:

```
array(2) {
  ["A_kitten"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Kitten.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpml5PIP"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["Another_kitten"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Kitten2.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpzhgXm0"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: but if want to get it with $_POST what is the key to get it ?

Comment: php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data". so should i change my enctype? if yes how it is posible ?

Comment: Sorry. Error on my side (my PHP is very rusty). `$_POST` is only appropriate for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. Use `$_FILES` to access the files.

Comment: oh im really greatful from you . now i can handel it thanks a milion and sory if i cant give you +1